# Create window with same aspect ratio as video in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window with the same dimensions as the window that mac os open when I click on a video, the video resolution is 1080x1920 or 9:16 aspect ratio, this is how it looks: [image]

Want to create a window from tkinter same as that, im using window config 1080x1920, but doesnt look nothing like that, looks horizontal [image]

Ss there a way I can make the window same as the one that mac open? Want to show like a preview how it would looks like when its done, so need the same dimensions.

```
self.background = tk.PhotoImage(file="./assets/test.png");
        
# background image
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=1080, height=1920, bg="white");
self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True);
self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.background, anchor="nw");
```

This is the code for the canvas background.

Comment: Try refering to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370910/how-to-resize-video-stream-from-cv2-according-to-tkinter-window

Comment: @plus. It is not 1080x1920. It is 1920x1080. 1080 is widely used vertical.

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes, but getting the info from the video its 1080x1920, width - height

Comment: Not width and height. OpenCV used height and width. Your monitor is widely used width and height

Comment: oh, well, in that case, isnt open cv the window, i want to create in tkinter the window with the same dimensions as the mac window, opencv when opens the video is fine, the problem is tkinter